# Need to correct :checked event in css

Tags: css

This is my code:

```
<style>
#hot{
display:none;
}
[id^=drop]:checked + div { display: block; }
</style>

<label for="drop-123" class="toggle">ENGLISH GRAMMAR</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="drop-123" />
<div id="hot">This text needs to be visible</div>
```

**This text needs to be visible** text is to be visible  after clicking on **ENGLISH GRAMMAR** .But I am not being able to figure out my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try adding it this way.

```
[id^=drop]:checked + #hot  {
  display: block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has more to do with CSS specificity.

```
#hot{
display:none;
}
[id^=drop]:checked + div#hot { display: block; }
```

`#id` is more specific than the `div` tag.

[Read](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

Use

#drop-123:checked + div {display:block;}

Comment: But I want use regular expression